# PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments JSON setPaymentOptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments transactions lacking the functionality of Standard PayPal transactions which contains Order ID,Item ID,Shipping Address by default. Some suggested if we use setPaymentOptions we can implement "inserting Shipping Address" in Adaptive Transactions but that also has been restricted to embed light box. Is there anyway we could achieve Shipping Address inclusion in the Adaptive transactions by JSON? Our Appln uses JSON data. We feel it is must for enabling the Seller Protection policy

Comment: SetPaymentOptions is your only option with Adaptive Payments.  You could switch to the Express Checkout APIs and that would have fewer limitations, but would require more development effort up front depending on what exactly you're doing with the payment.

Comment: Mine is muti-vendor marketplace where it involves Seller,me as store owner and buyer. Unfortunately I cannot go away with Adaptive. So basically  it is not possible with Adaptive-JSON for implementing Shipping address?

Comment: Yes, you can add the shipping address, but it has to be done with SetPaymentOptions.  There's no reason you couldn't switch to EC, though.  You can't do anything with Adaptive that you can't do with EC.  It's just a matter of the steps involved in getting it done.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the confirmation. I think i need to post requirements for customization to do this operation

Comment: Hi- I have implemented with actionType CREATE and call SetPaymentOptionsAPI with the Shipping address details and successfully completed the Transactions. but still i couldn't find the Address details on the Transaction details Page.Code [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/uYuR3aAkkP4DjU8eh5Mkxc) and Transaction Page [link](http://prnt.sc/cfitub)

Comment: Would be glad to know  what am missing in the API call?

Comment: @AndrewAngell Can you help on this query?

Comment: Need to see a sample of the Pay request/response and the SetPaymentOptions request/response.

Comment: @AndrewAngell have attached request/response captured for the complete transaction [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/6nitYiEQLm3HAuUbR4cFUV)

Comment: @AndrewAngell Did you get anything on the logs?

Comment: @AndrewAngell Did you see any errors from the log why it didn't get succeeded through actionType CREATE

Comment: The link you provided is dead.

Comment: Oh Sorry about that here it is Snapshot [link](http://prnt.sc/clqdmb) and log [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/bQ8YKkCVFPjfqHaBYpbUJA)

Comment: @AndrewAngell Andrew Would be great if we get a solution before link expires or can try to copy it local